# Find all natural numbers $m,n$ which :$m!+n!+10$ is perfect cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I would be interest to invesitigate for all  natural numbers $m,n$ which:

$m!+n!+10$ is perfect cube ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For $m,n\ge 5$, $m!+n!+10\equiv 10\pmod {20}$, which is not possible for cubes.

Thus you are left with asking if $n!+34$, $n!+16$, $n!+12$, $n!+11$ can be cubes.

Comment: This is better, since it leaves less cases to check.

Comment: If we work mod $4$ we get that one of $m,n$ is $\le 3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $m,n \geq 7$, we have that $m! \equiv n! \equiv 0 \mod 7$.

Therefore $m! + n! + 10 \equiv 3 \mod 7$.

But cubes are only 0, 1 and 6 mod 7.